# What is a good way to procedurally generate large tilemaps?

Tags: user-generated-content

I'm sorry if this question was already asked before.
The game I'm aiming to make is a 2D-top down game in similar fashion to Zelda. I'm generating tilemaps, simple grids with 16x16 pixels per tile, and I'm using cellular automata combined with some other methods to generate these tilemaps. I can generate fairly large tilemaps, but It's problematic to go too big and it seems very ineffiecent. To be able to have a big world I decided it was probably smart to divide everything up in smaller seamlessly connected tilemaps, but I'm really unsure how to actually deal with such a large map. Since I'm planning on having maybe 40x40 tiles per area, and 100x100 areas for the whole world that will add up to a ridiculous amount of tiles in total.
What is the best way to generate such a huge area and still letting it all flow together nicely and naturally? I'm currently generating a mini map of a world to get the general layout of the world. (100x100 pixels) And I could generate all of the areas seperately based on this layout, but i'm not sure it would allow me to create larger open and natural environments.
I see 3 different options:

1) Generating the whole map at once as the game is started, everything in one go, this including all the different regions like forests, lakes, mountains etc.

2) Breaking the areas down by the type of region, for example, getting the bounds of a forest area (which spans over several tilemaps) and then generating it with more detail, and moving on to other regions after that

3) Generating the areas one by one as you enter them, meaning the world will only be fully generated once you explored it all.

I appreciate all replies a lot! It's more of a general question and I imagine there are a lot of ways to do these, so any suggestions are welcome! Maybe I have the wrong approach altogether? I'm very new to procedural map generation so I apologise if I come off as very inexperienced
Thank you!

Comment: (40x40) x (100x100) isn't a completely ridiculous number of tiles. At the minimum, using one byte per tile it's only 16MB. In addition to the question you're asking, you might also try to figure out how much space you're using per tile, and whether you can use a more efficient memory layout (e.g., can you fit everything into 1 byte per tile?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I develop games as a hobby by myself and never actually talked or advised anyone about the details of game development before so my comment might be a bit off.

You say you use cellular automata to generate your map; I'm not sure but it sounds like every tile is reliant on one of the tiles before it to be generated, right? If that is the case you should definitely switch to a noise function such as simplex or Perlin, with these you can compute any coordinate irrespective of any other tiles on your map. The way I do it is I only calculate the tiles around visible and a bit outside the players view and I save the results in a cache so that the program doesn't have to keep recalculating the same tiles. Of course you should also limit the size of your cache also, so that the game doesn't keep data from areas the user visited way back for too long.

I think this guide could be helpful for you: http://www.redblobgames.com/maps/terrain-from-noise/